# Modify struct value inside dynamic struct function Golang

Tags: go, struct, interface

I have struct with setter function

```
package main

type Person struct {
   Name string
   Age int
}

func (p *Person) SetName(name string) {
   p.Name = name
}

func SomeMethod(human interface{}){
   // I call the setter function here, but doesn't seems exist
   human.SetName("Johnson")
}

func main(){
   p := Person{Name : "Musk"}
   SomeMethod(&p)
}
```

Got an error as follows :

> human.SetName undefined (type interface {} is interface with no
>   methods)

seems like func `SetName` doesn't included in `SomeMethod`

Why is it so? Any answer will be highly appreciated !

Comment: The empty interface `interface{}` has no methods. Is there a reason why you are using argument type `interface{}` instead of '*Person`?

Comment: Because I want to make it as generic/dynamic function that accepts any struct type @CeriseLimón

Comment: @Angger you need to implement the interface on `setter`

Comment: @Angger Update the question to state your actual goal.

Comment: It can't be totally generic. You can't call `SetName` on something with no `SetName` method. If you want to call `SetName` in the function, you have to specify that the argument is, at the very least, an interface that includes `SetName` with the same signature.

Answer (score 3):

Create an interface with `setName` and implement it on `Person` struct then call `SomeMethod` to set the value of `Person`

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Person struct {
   Name string
   Age int
}

type Human interface{
    SetName(name string)
}

func (p *Person) SetName(name string) {
   p.Name = name
}

func SomeMethod(human Human){
   human.SetName("Johnson")
}

func main(){
   p := &Person{Name : "Musk"}
   SomeMethod(p)
   fmt.Println(p)
}
```

[Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/SHgny1zWWs0)

To get the name using getter method for any struct pass through Human interface implement getter property on `Human` interface

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    )

type Person struct {
   Name string
   Age int
}

type Person2 struct{
   Name string
   Age int
}

type Human interface{
    getName() string
}

func (p *Person2) getName() string{
   return p.Name
}

func (p *Person) getName() string{
   return p.Name
}

func SomeMethod(human Human){
   fmt.Println(human.getName())
}

func main(){
   p := &Person{Name : "Musk"}
   SomeMethod(p)
   p2 := &Person2{Name: "Joe"}
   SomeMethod(p2)
}
```

[Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/R0bXpb_ydDl)

Comment: Can I make "SetName" func as dynamic too? coz I want everything that pass through SomeMethod automatically can use SetName method. @Himanshu

Comment: @Angger There is no automatic way to call a method. You have to call the method on given object encapsulated by `Human` interface.

Comment: but the SetName method inside Human is only belongs to Person. I want to make this SetName method also applied to any struct passes to SomeMethod? @Himanshu

Comment: @Angger It will be apply to any struct you pass inside the interface. Check updated code with getter to get the name you pass.